# How to update some variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know its almost the easiest thing in javascript but Im tried I can't get this work.
I just want some picture update some text that placed after them. If I put document.write in functions thats not good of course because it will make a whole new page.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="kepek">
      <img src="kepek/1.png" onclick="egy()">
      <img src="kepek/2.PNG">
      <img src="kepek/3.PNG">
      <img src="kepek/4.PNG">
      <img src="kepek/5.PNG">
    </div>
    <script>
      var osszeg = 0;

      function egy() {
        var osszeg = parseInt("8000");
        document.write(osszeg);
      }

      document.write(osszeg);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The thing I want to not clear the page but at the end of page (after the pictures) there should be shown a new number. and later I also want to update that number (without refresing the page, just clicking buttons/pictures...) I know its a dumb question. Thanks

Comment: To make that work you need to remove var in second variable. Thing is that this way you are making "local" variable that's private to that function. If you want to change "global" variable, don't use the var.

Comment: Have a look at DOM manipulation methods, such as [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild). Updating a variable is as simple as assigning a new value to it. Note though you have *two* variables with the same name. One is global, and the other is local to `egy`. I recommend to read a tutorial about JavaScript and DOM basics. E.g. http://quirksmode.org/js/contents.html is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create an element at the end of the page, and then show the value of `osszeg` in that element. Easy to achieve:

HTML:

```
<div id="osszeg"></div>
```

and in JS, when ever you want to update the `div`:

```
document.getElementById('osszeg').innerHTML = osszeg;
```

Notice also the comments to your question, you override the original value of `osszeg` by declaring it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use methods like `appendChild` or `innerHTML`. The code below will insert a span with an id="kepek-status" and set its innerHTML to osszeg every time you click. I'm not sure why you are parsing it as an int though, because you'll have to store it as a string anyway. `""+osszeg` converts it back to a string before storing it in the new span.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="kepek">
      <img src="kepek/1.png" onclick="egy()">
      <img src="kepek/2.PNG">
      <img src="kepek/3.PNG">
      <img src="kepek/4.PNG">
      <img src="kepek/5.PNG">
    </div>
    <script>
      var osszeg = 0;

      function egy() {
        var kepek = document.getElementById('kepek');
        var status = document.getElementById('kepek-status');
        if (!status) {
          status = document.createElement("span");
          status.setAttribute("id", "kepek-status");
          kepek.appendChild(status);
        }
        var osszeg = parseInt("8000");
        status.innerHTML = ""+osszeg;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```